# Ubuntu: Open Netbeans in specific workspace (using window matching)

Tags: ubuntu, netbeans, ubuntu-13.10, compiz

Using the `CompizConfig Settings Manager` on Ubuntu 13.10 I would like to assign Netbeans 7.4 to workspace 4 (viewport X=2, Y=2) and have it maximized. This approach works just fine for `Chromium` and `Thunderbird`. The problem is that using the `class=Netbeans IDE 7.4` is not doing anything, and the `name=sun-awt-X11-XFramePeer` is not matching my Netbeans instance either.

How do I configure my CompizConfig Window Placement to place Netbeans in the appropriate workspace?

Answer (score 1):

spaces need to be escaped in most shell envoirements, because spaces could indicate different arguments.
try:

```
class="Netbeans IDE 7.4"
```

or:

```
class=Netbeans\ IDE\ 7.4
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately this did not solve my problems; Netbeans still launches in my current workspace, not maximized.